# Three ways to call a method in Java - Static vs non static

Tags: java, static

I am trying to figure out different ways to call methods, and during experimenting, I have come up with 3 ways to do something.

```
public static boolean isFoo(int bar) {
    return bar % 2 == 0;
}

//in a driver class:
foo.isFoo(7);
```

or

```
public static int foo;

public Foo(int foo) {
    this.foo = foo;

public boolean isFoo() {
    return foo % 2 == 0;
}

//in a driver class:
Foo foo = new Foo(4);
System.out.println(foo.isFoo());
```

or

```
public static int foo;

public Foo(int foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}

public static int getFoo() {
    return foo;
}

public static boolean isFoo(Foo foo) {
    return foo.getFoo() % 2 == 0;
}


//in a driver class:
Foo foo = new Foo(14);
System.out.println(Foo.isFoo(foo));
```

***Which of these 3 ways are considered static and why?*** I'm not sure because they all use the word static, thus I believe that in the driver, I would be referring to all of them in a static context. Are they all static?

I have attempted googling but none seem to connect to my situation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *"Which of these methods are considered static and why?"* - any method marked as `static`

Comment: There's no `static` method in your second snippet.

Comment: Also, although you can invoke static methods on reference expressions, don't.

Comment: In the second example `int foo` is `static`, which is very, very dangrous.  A `static` method has no "instance" attached to it, so you don't need an instance of `Foo` to call them

Comment: @Mad in the second example  I could have made it `public int foo` and it would've still worked? Or does that mean that I can remove the first line altogether?

Comment: In that case you'd be able to access foo directly using Foo.foo

Comment: @Mad very well. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only 2 static methods, first and third. Second one is instance method.

Coming to your actual question, do not over think. Keep the most clean and readable way. Perfect static method I would say here is

```
public static boolean isFoo(int bar) {
    return bar % 2 == 0;
}
```